# VBS, can't delete folder on desktop

Tags: vbscript, permissions

I'm facing a problem with VBS when i try delete to a folder on desktop, error is permission denied.
My code here below :

```
DesktopPath= WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    if (fso.folderExists (DesktopPath + "\toto")) Then fso.DeleteFolder DesktopPath + "\toto" End If
```

The error does not occur everytime, sometimes it works and sometimes don't!
Any help is very much apreciated!

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I suspect your code is fine, even though you do not show how `WshShell` and `fso` are defined ;).  Anyhow, here's some things to check: Is that folder controlled by a group policy, perhaps?  Is the folder empty?  Do you have anything open from that folder when you try to delete it?  Are any programs running from that folder location?  Have you tried stopping your anti-virus program before deleting the folder? You could try adding `, True` before `End If` in order to force delete read-only folders.  Hope this info helps.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer ! I'll try to add, ```,True``` to the script.

Comment: Hello, i've added ```,True``` and the end of the line but the problem is still the same, permission denied when trying to delete a folder on desktop... If anyone got another idea it would be great ! Thank you :)